# Custom Admin Django

Tags: django, django-admin, django-1.9

Estou tentando alterar a tela de login para uma nova tela personalizada, 
mas não está funcionando.

https://github.com/rg3915/custom-admin

Eu configurei o settings:

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates_admin')],
```

Criei as pastas e templates

https://github.com/rg3915/custom-admin/tree/master/myproject/core/templates_admin/admin

Mas não está funcionando.

Comment: Regis, você poderia adicionar mais informações a pergunta? Você tem pistas que indique o motivo de não estar funcionando a alteração na tela de login?

Comment: configura o seu `static files` da uma olhada nesse exemplo, acho q vai ajudar https://github.com/brumazzi/DJango-Exemples/tree/master/Static_File

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A documentação https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#admin-overriding-templates informa que basta criar a pasta templates/admin/ dentro da app, no meu caso myproject/core/

Neste caso, a ordem das apps importa.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # my apps
    'myproject.core',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    ...
```